# EAGLE PCB GND Plane not properly connecting to through hole pins

Tags: pcb-design, ground, eaglecad, ground-plane

So I submitted this board design to PCBWay to get prototypes, but they kicked it back to me saying that there are very thin wires throughout the board. Upon inspecting the pictures they sent back to me, it looks like all of my through hole GND pins that are suppose to connect to the bottom GND plane are only getting connected via these small thin lines. Previous revisions of this board did not have any issue with this and the only thing that I changed for this revision is that I added another GND plane to the top side of the PCB. Would this affect anything? If so, how do I correct it? PCBWay has offered to remove the lines for their assembly files, but I'm afraid that if they remove them, those pins won't connect at all.

[image]

Comment: There should be a setting somewhere for thermal relief spokes width.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an easy fix. Overlooked the "width" setting of the polygons that I drew for the planes. It was set to 0, so while the plane was good to go, the GND connections didn't exist.
[image]